# Show Second HTML5 Video When First Video End

Tags: html, video

Basically what I'm trying to do is get my first video to play when the page opens and then once it finishes, I want a second video to appear below it.

I've played around with it a bunch and am certain it's something obvious that I'm missing.

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secondVid").hide()  
    $("#firstVid").bind("ended",function(){
            $("#secondVid").show();
    });    
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="firstVid" class="videoWrapper" >
                <video controls autoplay>
                    <source src="video.mp4">
                    <source src="video.ogv">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="secondVid" class="videoWrapper" >
                <video controls>
                    <source src="video.mp4">
                    <source src="video.ogv">
                </video>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is call `play` after the first video is shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secondVid").hide()  
    $("#firstVid").bind("ended",function(){
            $("#secondVid").show()
                .find("video").get(0).play();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Had no luck with this.